# Trying to merge two data sets by matching two fields (Date and Name), where one data set might not have an entry with matching Date

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-dates

I have two tables:
Table#1 is Store Name, Date, Hours.
Table#2 is Store Name, Date, Sales.

Need to merge the two based on Name and Date, but there are entries on Table#2 that doesn't exist in Table#1 due to Store not open that day, but a sale was posted to that Store while the Store is closed.
How can I incorporate a formula to merge the Sales number from Table#2 to the last occurrence of Store Name based on the entry Date?

Comment: [Welcome to Web App Stack Exchange!](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour) Can you share a copy of your spreadsheet, with all sensitive information removed?

Comment: @DavidTan 
Adding the google sheet as suggested:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1lWF21HykEKSXcOFTIBC-uQdG_PCZ73ggGBYbNw5Qk7E/edit#gid=667528302

Comment: Hello @Andrew, can you check the test result tab? If this is close enough to what you want to happen, please do let me know so that I can document my answer. I'm rather unsure whether this is want you want to happen.

Comment: Hi @DavidTan, thanks for the attempt.  It looks like it is missing a few of the sales that didn't have a matching date with hours.  I'm not sure if it is even possible to capture those to embed into the table.